# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to connect my java application to mysql workbench. all the details in connection string, username and password are correct, even though the connection is not getting established

[image]

[image]

and throwing the error

[image]

### com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

From the coverage I came to know that the connection statement is not executing, but I don't know why?

[image]

could you please explain me what went wrong. please and thanks.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, post the code as text (indented with four space so it is rendered as code block). And please post the full exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you specified `MySQL` in the JDBC URL instead of `mysql` (notice the case difference).

You should also close the result set, statement and connection at the end.

Comment: Can you confirm that you can successfully connect to the MySQL server/database with MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

To connect workbench to a database, first you must have a running sql server. So first of all make sure you have a running server. Then loose the "?autoReconnect=ture&useSSL=false" part in your database connection URL and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I suffered for more than 3-4 hours with it, and finally one of my senior suggested me to check the version of my SQLconnector and SQL Workspace's version.
Then I found that it was because of the mismatch of both of them. Please check this thing first, and still if it doesn't work, then use the below query.

?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=GMT

add this after your URL as it is a Master Quick Fix.